# display attributes without nesting objects using include in (Sequelize)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I have a model SKUValue and it is associated with two other models **VariantOptions** and **ProductVariant**.
I created a sequelize query that *"left-joins"* **SKUValue** value with **VariantOptions** and **ProductVariant**, and brings brings result.

**Sequelize query**

```
await SKUValue.findAll({
            where: {
                productId: '7bde8a1d-5f6c-4349-bfda-428399c88291'
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: VariantOption,
                    attributes: ['name']
                },
                {
                    model: ProductVariant,
                    attributes: ['name']
                }
            ],
            attributes: ['SKUId']
        });
```

The query result returns an array where the attributes **VariantOption** and **ProductVariant** are a nested object and has only one field.

```
[
    {
        "SKUId": "72edd3ca-fa12-4234-ba8c-dd008eb416d5",
        "VariantOption": {
            "name": "Large"
        },
        "ProductVariant": {
            "name": "Size"
        }
    },
    {
        "SKUId": "72edd3ca-fa12-4234-ba8c-dd008eb416d5",
        "VariantOption": {
            "name": "Red"
        },
        "ProductVariant": {
            "name": "color"
        }
    }
]
```

How do I query the attributes in such a way the result of **VariantOption** and **ProductVariant** does not return a nested object but only a stirng.

In general I want the result to be something like this

```
[
    {
        "SKUId": "72edd3ca-fa12-4234-ba8c-dd008eb416d5",
        "VariantOption.name": "Large",
        "ProductVariant.name": "Size"
    },
    {
        "SKUId": "72edd3ca-fa12-4234-ba8c-dd008eb416d5",
        "VariantOption.name": "Red",
        "ProductVariant.name": "Color"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.

Using **Sequelize.literal**, we can easily add the inner attributes in the outer attributes.

```
return await SKUValue.findAll({
            where: {
                productId: '7bde8a1d-5f6c-4349-bfda-428399c88291'
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: VariantOption,
                    attributes: []
                },
                {
                    model: ProductVariant,
                    attributes: []
                }
            ],
            attributes: [
                'SKUId',
                [Sequelize.literal('"ProductVariant"."name"'), 'productVariant'],
                [Sequelize.literal('"VariantOption"."name"'), 'variantOption']
            ]
        });
```